# Telerik set application theme from XAML

Tags: silverlight, xaml, telerik

Is it possible to set application wide theme from XAML in Telerik? There is only a code-behind example. I would like to set in in XAML and have a Metro theme in design-mode too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could achieve this as follows:

```
<Application
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"     
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    x:Class="SilverlightApplication.App">
        <Application.Resources>
            <telerik:MetroTheme x:Key="Theme" IsApplicationTheme="True"/>
        </Application.Resources>
 </Application>
```

Comment: Thanks! I was missing the IsApplicationTheme attribute.

Answer (score 2):

This did not work for me at first.  It threw the follwoing exceptions:

> {System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key was
>   not present in the dictionary.    at
>   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)    at
>   System.Windows.ResourceManagerWrapper.GetResourceForUri(Uri xamlUri,
>   Type componentType)}
>
> Set property 'Telerik.Windows.Controls.Theme.ApplicationThemeSetter'
>   threw an exception. [Line: 53 Position: 70]

I tried declaring it in the App.xaml and the Generic.xaml but the same result.

I also tried to set the theme in the XAML like:

```
<t:RadGridView t:StyleManager.Theme="Windows8Theme" ..../>
```

But this has no affect.

NOTE: I'm using 2012's Q3

I solved the problem eventually.  You have to include the theme DLL.  So in my case I wanted to use the Windows8Theme, I needed to add a reference to the **Telerik.Windows.Themes.Windows8.dll**.  It would be helpful if Telerik's code throw an exception saying as much, but "hey", that's just me.

- Rashad

Comment: You should read the documentation first [like in here](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/silverlight/controls/radtabcontrol/styling-and-appearance/using-themes)